# How is the dimension of the following basis 3?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given a set of vectors containing $\{ [111], [-3 -3 -3],[555]\}$
I'm not sure if memory serves me right, but aren't the $2$ other vectors scalar multiples of $[111]$? Wouldn't that mean the dimension of the basis is $1$?

The correction states the dimension is $3$, and I am currently confused.

Thanks

Comment: Your language doesn't make much sense: we don't speak of the dimension of a *basis* but of the dimension of a *vector space*. If the vector space is spanned by a finite number of vectors, the dimension of the vector space is defined to be the number of vectors in any basis of the space. In other words, the dimension of a (finite-dimensional) space is the number (cardinality) of vectors in a basis for the space.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to imply that: I find the basis of the set, and the dimension is simply the number of vectors in that basis.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. But you didn't tell us what your "set" (presumably you mean vector space) is. You've only told us it **contains** certain vectors, all of which lie in the span of $(1,1,1)$. But this leaves open the possibility that your set contains vectors *not* on that line. So it very well could be the case that your set has dimension 3. You need to clarify exactly what space you're dealing with. The dimension will then be the number of vectors in the basis of that space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dimension of the basis is 1. Any vector of these 3 forms a basis.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. The OP says his space **contains** the three vectors. This leaves open the possibility that there may be other vectors in the space that are not in the span of $(1,1,1)$.